# JsonString to object with data is not array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I get data from an API in public web, and this API return a JSONString as below:

```
`{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17080450.0, 
        "total_supply": 17080450.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 7675.65, 
                "volume_24h": 4815480000.0, 
                "market_cap": 131103556043.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.24, 
                "percent_change_24h": 0.72, 
                "percent_change_7d": 1.48
            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 1.0, 
                "volume_24h": 627370.9718395185, 
                "market_cap": 17080450.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0, 
                "percent_change_24h": 0, 
                "percent_change_7d": 0
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1528385974
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Litecoin", 
        "symbol": "LTC", 
        "website_slug": "litecoin", 
        "rank": 6, 
        "circulating_supply": 56877198.0, 
        "total_supply": 56877198.0, 
        "max_supply": 84000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 120.933, 
                "volume_24h": 356821000.0, 
                "market_cap": 6878330197.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.27, 
                "percent_change_24h": -0.06, 
                "percent_change_7d": 1.1
            }, 
            "BTC": {
                "price": 0.0157554083, 
                "volume_24h": 46487.3984613681, 
                "market_cap": 896123.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": -0.03, 
                "percent_change_24h": -0.78, 
                "percent_change_7d": -0.38
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1528385943
    }
], 
"metadata": {
    "timestamp": 1528385873, 
    "num_cryptocurrencies": 1645, 
    "error": null
}
}`
```

I already created a class to get data from this API, this is my code:

```
public class CryCurClass
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<data> data;

    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    public object metadata;
}

public class data
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("website_slug")]
    public string Website_slug { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("rank")]
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("circulating_supply")]
    public Nullable<float> Circulating_supply { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total_supply")]
    public float Total_supply { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("max_supply")]
    public Nullable<float> Max_supply { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qoutes")]
    public Qoutes Qoutes { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("last_updated")]
    public string Last_updated { get; set; }

}

public class Qoutes
{
    [JsonProperty("USD")]
    public info USD { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty("BTC")]
    public info BTC {set;get ;}
}

public class info
{
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public Nullable<float> Price { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("volume_24h")]
    public Nullable<float> Volume_24h { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("market_cap")]
    public Nullable<float> Market_cap { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("percent_change_1h")]
    public Nullable<float> Percent_change_1h { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("percent_change_24h")]
    public Nullable<float> Percent_change_24h { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("percent_change_7d")]
    public Nullable<float> Percent_change_7d { set; get; }
}
```

But when I try to convert JsonString to class, with code as: `CryCurClass jsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CryCurClass>(_strAnswer);` variable **Qoutes** always return null. I realize this variable is not a regular array, but I don't know how to build class to be contain it.
I think my class is not match with this JSonString but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON API is returning an Object called "quotes". 
Your DeserializeObject is looking for an object called "qoutes".

Answer (score 0):

is it because you have a spelling mistake in your Qoutes? in Json you have quotes and your class name is Qoutes.

For simplicity use this site to generate your classes from Json.
http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class USD
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double market_cap { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_7d { get; set; }
}

public class BTC
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double market_cap { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_7d { get; set; }
}

public class Quotes
{
    public USD USD { get; set; }
    public BTC BTC { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string website_slug { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public double circulating_supply { get; set; }
    public double total_supply { get; set; }
    public double max_supply { get; set; }
    public Quotes quotes { get; set; }
    public int last_updated { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public int num_cryptocurrencies { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my bad :D ty

Comment: Glad I can help. can you accept this as an answer? so, I can help other people.